# Is there a way to wrap REST Controller responses with metadata using Spring-Boot annotations?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am writing a Spring-boot RESTful api/Angular webapp that retrieves information about games from a database. I ran into an issue where I needed to add metadata to the api responses.

As of right now I am using this class to wrap the responses within a HashMap in order to add the metadata. I feel like this implementation isn't the best - ultimately I would like to be using a Spring annotation such as `@ControllerAdvice`, although I already attempted that and had some issues handling exceptions.

I would like to know if there is a more efficient solution that uses built-in Spring annotations/structures. I feel like there is most likely an annotation that I can use to automatically pass each controller response through `addMetadata`

Here is the current metadata wrapper that I've implemented:

**MetadataHandler.class**

```
@Service
public class MetadataHandler {
    public HashMap<String, Object> addMetadata(Object obj){
        HashMap<String, Object> response = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        HashMap<String, Object> metadata = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        if(obj == null){
            return null;
        } else if(obj instanceof List){
            metadata.put("_records", ((List<?>) obj).size());

            response.put("data", obj);
            response.put("metadata", metadata);
        } else if(obj instanceof DbModelObj) {
            metadata.put("_records", 1);

            response.put("data", obj);
            response.put("metadata", metadata);
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

And here are the controllers that use the handler class:

**GameController.class**

```
@RequestMapping("api/v1/game")
@RestController
public class GameController {

    private final GameService gameService;

    private final MetadataHandler metadataHandler;

    @Autowired
    public GameController(GameService gameService, MetadataHandler metadataHandler) {
        this.gameService = gameService;
        this.metadataHandler = metadataHandler;
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/all")
    public HashMap<String, Object> getAllGames(){
        return metadataHandler.addMetadata(gameService.getAllGames());
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/byId")
    public HashMap<String, Object> getGameById(@RequestParam("id") int id){
        return metadataHandler.addMetadata(gameService.getGameById(id));
    }
}
```

**UserController.class**

```
@RequestMapping("api/v1/user")
@RestController
public class UserController {

    private final UserService userService;

    private final MetadataHandler metadataHandler;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService, MetadataHandler metadataHandler) {
        this.metadataHandler = metadataHandler;
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public void addUser(@Valid @NonNull @RequestBody User user){
        userService.addUser(user);
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/all")
    public HashMap<String, Object> getAllUsers() {
        return metadataHandler.addMetadata(userService.getAllUsers());
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/byId")
    public HashMap<String, Object> getUserById(@RequestParam("id") int id) {
        return metadataHandler.addMetadata(userService.getUserById(id));
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/byUsername")
    public HashMap<String, Object> getUserByUsername(@RequestParam("username") String username) {
        return metadataHandler.addMetadata(userService.getUserByUsername(username));
    }

    @DeleteMapping(path = "/byId")
    public void deleteUserById(@RequestParam("id") int id){
        userService.deleteUser(id);
    }

    @PutMapping(path = "/byId")
    public void updateUser(@RequestParam("id") int id, @Valid @NonNull @RequestBody User userToUpdate){
        userService.updateUser(id, userToUpdate);
    }
}
```

Comment: As it's currently written, this question is opinion-based (elegant is subjective). Please [edit] your post to clarify an objective standard you are looking for.

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs done. Changed the wording to be more specific.